# How to render HTML using a Ruby on Rails 5 API Application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5

We're using Ruby on Rails 5.0.0.1 in API-Mode. What Middleware and Configurations do I need to add, in order to being able to render html instead of json in an controller.

Edit:

Thank you all for your answers.

Want I wanted is to render normal `erb/haml` views. not html in json like 'kartik upadhyay' mentioned. Since the Application is primary an JSON API we didn't want the full blown default Rails Installation, which mean our Application Controller extends from `ActionController::API`.

My Plan was to make a PdfRendering Controller which includes all Modules needed for ActionView to work. What I rather did was reading the asset pipeline (because we wanted to use sass) and inherit the application controller from `ActionController::Base`. as other rails apps would do.

It's not the nicest solution since you're including the whole ActionController::Base and all of it's Feature that you may not be using. But it's still slimmer that a full Blown Rails installation (especially the middleware aka. sessions etc.)

Comment: You can use templates without using the whole Rails framework. Just add `slim` or `haml`, then you can do something like `Slim::Template.new(path).render(Object.new, users: users)` and it renders html for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
  include ActionView::Layouts
  include ActionController::Rendering
```

Add these to your controller

Comment: may i know what each of these modules do?

Comment: ActionView::Layouts provides Layout and include ActionController::Rendering provides template rendering.
With them, you can render *.html.erb

Answer (score -1):

You can use render to string method of rails for rendering your html as string inside json, put this inside your controller:

`render json: { data: render_to_string('html_file_name') }`

this will render html as response like:

```
{"data": "<html>\n<h3>hello</h3>\n</html>"}
```

Comment: This is now what he asked for.

Answer (score -1):

you can render erb/haml/slim etc. files like the following:

```
format.html { render :file_name }
```

Answer (score -5):

You can simply use this gem **RABL**.

https://github.com/nesquena/rabl