# Rails reset password link issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, reset-password

I have created a forget password functionality.i am using rails api mode only and my rails version is 7.0.4.problem is when i get reset password link in mail if i click on that i can not see anything page is not showing anything.which should show form for password reset.

My controller

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user.present?
      # user.send_reset_password_instructions
      UserMailer.with(user: user).reset_instructions.deliver_now
      render json: { message: 'Password reset instructions sent' }
    else
      render json: { message: 'User not found' }, status: :not_found
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by(reset_password_token: params[:user][:reset_password_token])

    if @user && @user.reset_password_sent_at > 2.hours.ago
      if @user.update(password_params)
        @user.update(reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil)
        redirect_to login_path, notice: 'Your password has been reset successfully'
      else
        render :edit
      end
    else
      # Invalid reset password token
      render json: { error: 'Invalid reset password token or token has expired' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  def edit
    @user = User.find_by(reset_password_token: params[:reset_password_token])
    if @user
      # The reset password token is valid, render the password reset form
      @reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
      render :edit
    else
      # Invalid reset password token
      render json: { error: 'Invalid reset password token' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  private

  def password_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

routes.rb file

```
  get 'password/reset', to: 'password_resets#new', as: 'new_password_reset'
  post 'password/reset', to: 'password_resets#create', as: 'create_password_reset'
  get 'password/reset/edit/:reset_password_token', to: 'password_resets#edit', as: :edit_password_reset
  patch 'password/reset/edit', to: 'password_resets#update', as: :password_reset
```

View

```
<h1>Reset Password</h1>
<%= form_with(url: password_reset_path, method: :patch) do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :reset_password_token, value: @reset_password_token %>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>

  <%= form.submit 'Reset Password' %>
<% end %>
```

User mailer

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def reset_instructions
    @user = params[:user]
    @reset_password_link = edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_password_token)
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Password reset instructions')
  end


end
```

I have tried many solutions but nothis is working i have seen my console but i there are no errors and on server logs it is showing everything okay

```
Started GET "/password/reset/edit/848f365b993d2e6aef3cafcf42fdaf0234c09fe82a3026a828696112c06f2fb0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-05-17 12:13:28 +0500
Processing by PasswordResetsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
  User Load (15.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["reset_password_token", "[FILTERED]"], ["L
IMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:29:in `edit'
Completed 200 OK in 241ms (Views: 10.4ms | ActiveRecord: 15.3ms | Allocations: 610)
```

Comment: The problem is probably related to API mode, which doesnt render HTML. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612452/how-to-render-html-using-a-ruby-on-rails-5-api-application

Comment: thank you this works now i am facing issue when i hit this url which in is in reset passsword link http://localhost:3000/password/reset/edit/848f365b993d2e6aef3cafcf42fdaf0234c09fe82a3026a828696112c06f2fb0                                                                                              then i get this error undefined local variable or method `password_reset_url' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000c8a0>
Did you mean?  password_url

Comment: now i am facing new error in which it is saying undefined local variable or method `password_reset_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000013970>
Did you mean?  password_path

Comment: Make a new Stack Overflow post for your new error.